# Does Scheme/Racket have an enumeration operation?

Tags: haskell, lisp, scheme, enumeration, racket

Does Scheme/Racket have an enumeration notation equivalent to the [a..b] notation in Haskell?
In Haskell, [1..5] evaluates to a list [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: The selling point of Lisp is minimal syntax. So instead of special notation, like `[a..b]`, there are functions that accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

1. `(for/list ([i (in-range 1 6)]) i)`
2. `(sequence->list (in-range 1 6))`
3. `(require srfi/1) (iota 5 1)`

Answer (score 4):

1. `(for/list ([i 5]) (+ 1 i))`
2. `(build-list 5 add1)`

Also, `(in-range 1 6)` (which is a [sequence](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html)) by itself is useful in many contexts.

Comment: To get behavior most like Haskell, use Lazy Racket's `build-list` which is (surprise) lazy.